# Remove parenthesis AND text within from folder names

Tags: batch-file, scripting, directory

I was curious if there may be an easy way to rename about 300-400 folders (in one directory) by removing the parenthesis and the text inside.  I have movies I've ripped over the years and was wanting to rename the FOLDER ONLY and leave the contents within the folder untouched.

Example:

Current folder name: **The Movie Folder (2014)**

New changed folder name: **The Movie Folder**

Any help is appreciated!  I've seen a few posts about changing the filenames etc.. but it's been a long time since I've messed with .bat files and scripting.

Comment: Lol how about mentioning your operating system?

Comment: Windows 7 is the OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your description of the problem is somewhat vague, so I made some assumptions. The Batch file below assume that all folders ends in `" (YYYY)"`, so it just remove the last 7 characters. If this is not what you want, please describe more precisely the format and position of the text to remove.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir /B /AD') do (
   set "name=%%a"
   ren "%%a" "!name:~0,-7!"
)
```

Comment: Actually... that is perfect for what I need :) Also to clarify, yes, the last 7 characters need to be removed and it works like a charm!

Comment: @Shane: Just as reference: removing text enclosed in parentheses is _much more difficult_ than just remove the last N characters. Try to state your future requests in simpler Batch terms...